Differential equation by the parameter variation method
I need help to solve this equation by the method of parameters variation (Wronskian):
$$4\,y''-3\,y'=x\,e^{\frac{3}{4}\,x}$$
I know the solution of the differential equation is:
$$y=\dfrac{{x}^{2}\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{6}-\dfrac{4\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+C_{1}\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}+C$$
But when I try the parameter variation method, I get:
$$y=\dfrac{{64}\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{27}+\dfrac{{4x}^{2}\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{6}-\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+C_{1}\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}+C$$
I think I'm wrong with the first Wronskian:
Homogeneous solution:
$$4\lambda^{2}-3\lambda=0$$
$$\lambda(4\lambda-3)=0$$
$$\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=3/4$$
$$\therefore y_h= C + C_1e^{\frac{3}{4}x}$$
Particular solution
$$y_p= y_1 + y_2e^{\frac{3}{4}x}$$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y'_1+y'_2e^{\frac{3}{4}x} =0 \\ 
y'_1+y'_2[e^{\frac{3}{4}x}]' =Q(x) 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Where $Q(x)=x\,e^{\frac{3}{4}\,x}$
$$W =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{\frac{3}{4}x} \\
0 & \frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x} 
\end{bmatrix} = (1*\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x})(e^{\frac{3}{4}x}*0)=\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}-0=\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}$$
Find y'_1
$$y'_1=\frac{W_1}{W} =\dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & e^{\frac{3}{4}x}  \\
Q(x) & \frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x} 
\end{bmatrix}}{W} = \dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & e^{\frac{3}{4}x}  \\
x\,e^{\frac{3}{4}\,x} & \frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x} 
\end{bmatrix}}{W} = 0 -\dfrac{xe^{2(\frac{3}{4}x)}}{\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}} = -\dfrac{xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}}{\frac{3}{4}}$$
Integrate y'_1 to find out y_1
$$\frac{dy}{dx}_1=-\dfrac{xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}}{\frac{3}{4}} = dy_1=-\dfrac{xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}}{\frac{3}{4}}dx = \int dy_1= \int -\dfrac{xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}}{\frac{3}{4}}dx $$
$$y_1 = -\frac{4}{3}\int xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}dx \implies y_1=\dfrac{64\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{27}-\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+K_1 $$
Find y'_2
$$y'_2=\frac{W_2}{W} =\dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & Q(x) 
\end{bmatrix}}{W} = \dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & x\,e^{\frac{3}{4}\,x} 
\end{bmatrix}}{W} = \dfrac{e^{\frac{3}{4}\,x}-0}{\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}} = \dfrac{x}{\frac{3}{4}}$$
Integrate y'_2 to find out y_2
$$\frac{dy}{dx}_2=\dfrac{x}{\frac{3}{4}} = dy_2=\dfrac{x}{\frac{3}{4}}dx = \int dy_2= \int \dfrac{x}{\frac{3}{4}}dx $$
$$y_2 = \frac{4}{3}\int xdx \implies y_2=\dfrac{4\,{x}^{2}}{6}+K_2$$
General solution y = y_h + y_p
$$y = C + C_1e^{\frac{3}{4}x} + \dfrac{64\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{27}-\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+K_1 + (\dfrac{4\,{x}^{2}}{6}+K_2) e^{\frac{3}{4}x} $$
$$y = C + K_1  + C_1e^{\frac{3}{4}x} + \dfrac{64\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{27}-\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+ \dfrac{4\,{x}^{2}}{6}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}+K_2e^{\frac{3}{4}x}  $$
$$y = C + (C_1+K_2+\dfrac{64}{27})e^{\frac{3}{4}x} -\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+ \dfrac{4\,{x}^{2}}{6}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}$$
$$y = C + C_1e^{\frac{3}{4}x} -\dfrac{16\,x\,{e}^{\frac{3\,x}{4}}}{9}+ \dfrac{4\,{x}^{2}}{6}e^{\frac{3}{4}x}$$
Everything comes out almost the same until I reach the final result, where I have an extra 4 multiplying that shouldn't be there.

Can you also share the setup of your integrals? It's possible there may be a mistake there.

Do you mean these? $y_1 = -\frac{3}{4}\int xe^{\frac{3}{4}x}dx$  $y_2 = \frac{3}{4}\int xdx$

Please just edit that into your post.

Sorry! I'm new, those are my integrals

Please include both integrals and what you think the results are within your post, not in comments. (The lead-up to these steps are also relevant.)

The integrals mentioned by Sean Roberson depend on the RHS of the differential equation. It must be normalized in such a way that the coefficient of $y''$ is $1$..

Now I added all the process I did

Thanks! So when my highest order term is with a constant, should I always isolate the constant?

I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the help

Why don't you start with $y(x)=e^{\frac{3x}{4}},z(x)$ to make $4z''+3z'=x$ ? It will be much simpler
